# Can eclipse monitor an arbitrary log file in the Console view?

Tags: eclipse, logging, console, log4j

I am launching my JBoss server in eclipse, and so standard out/err displays in the Console view. But there are other logs being generated by log4j, and so I need to be able to monitor some of those as well. Is there anyway to "tail" an arbitrary file - with the nice source code hyperlinks that the Console view provides, of course.

(I am using myeclipse 7.5, which is eclipse 3.4.2)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I currently am using **[NTail](https://web.archive.org/web/20110318103654/http://www.certiv.net/products/ntail.html)** ([Eclipse market place](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ntail)):
You can define several "NTail views", each one monitoring one or several files.

[image: http://www.certiv.net/images/NTailScreenShot001.jpg]

See also [Log file viewer for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802409/log-file-viewer-for-eclipse/802419#802419)

Comment: @VonC, thanks NTail looks good. Perhaps a little too easy to truncate the underlying log file, but a nice little analog to the builtin Console view.

Comment: NTail website seems to be down

Comment: oh yer it's back up now. must have just been temporary. you could still access it with Google's cache version anyway...

Answer (score 5):

I just searched the Eclipse Marketplace for

> log file viewer

and it suggested [LogViewer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/logviewer), which does exactly what you need very well (+more).