# How to view a log file in Eclipse editor just like it looks in console window?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tail

I have a txt log file.
How to make it look in Eclipse editor just as if it was the console output [ eg links underlined ].

It is a bit sad plugins called "Log viewer" do not highlight links as Console Window does. That's the worst thing about such plugins.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069245/can-eclipse-monitor-an-arbitrary-log-file-in-the-console-view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As chburd mentions, **[NTail](http://www.certiv.net/products/ntail.html)** is a good candidate (as I said in "[Can eclipse monitor an arbitrary log file in the Console view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069245/can-eclipse-monitor-an-arbitrary-log-file-in-the-console-view/1069468#1069468)")

[image]

You can also define your own Console Viewer (see [**this source**](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/console/TextConsoleViewer.java.htm)) to define your own hyperlink.

Comment: @VonC Tell me please, what are the rules NTail uses to handle stack trace hyperlinks? Eclipse hangs up when I try to follow a specific hyperlink. But others do work ok, I can follow other links and the source java file opens.

Comment: That is strange, because those hyperlinks are created based on a certain regex (xxx.java: line), so if the file exist in the current project, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed [NTail](http://www.certiv.net/projects/ntail.html), I think it is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Aptana (www.aptana.com) has a really nice tail view feature for Eclipse.  Highly recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

I use [LOG Viewer](https://github.com/anb0s/logviewer) for eclipse. Which works very well and allows customization.