# BIRT: logging to eclipse console

Tags: birt

Need help in setting up BIRT logging.

Birt: 2.6.2
Eclipse: 3.6.2 (reporting)

I am able to log from within the eclipse birt designer to file as instructed [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Scripting#Q%3a_How_can_I_log_javascript.3F).

But not sure how to redirect the logs to eclipse standard console. Tried the following script but didn't work:

```
importPackage(Packages.java.util.logging);

var cHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
cHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
var rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
logger.addHandler(cHandler);

Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround can be [NTail](http://www.certiv.net/products/ntail.html%20NTail) plugin.

Log whatever you want to a file, then monitor this file with NTail. See [this answer about logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069245/can-eclipse-monitor-an-arbitrary-log-file-in-the-console-view/1069468#1069468).

Even if you want to monitor Eclipse stdout (redirected to a file) with Eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a logging configuration file? You don't need one necessarily, but if you don't set your log level in a configuration file, maybe you have to set it at runtime:

```
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

If this doesn't work either you could also try to use [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) instead of `java.utils.logging`.